# Passing all arguments in zsh function

Tags: function, find, arguments, zsh

I am trying to write a simple function in my .zshrc that hides all the errors (mostly "Permission denied") for `find`.

Now, how can I pass all the arguments given by calling the function to `find`?

```sh
function superfind() {
    echo "Errors are suppressed!"
    find $(some magic here) 2>/dev/null
}
```

I could do `$1 $2 $3 $4 ...` but this is stupid! I am sure there is a really simple way.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Use `$@`, it expands to all the positional arguments, e.g.:

```sh
superfind () {
    echo "Errors are suppressed!"
    find "$@" 2> /dev/null
}
```

Comment: supposing you wanted to pass all but the first argument?

Comment: @rayandrews: add a `shift` command before the `find` command.

Comment: I mean in a situation like this: "echo "first arg is: $1 and the remaining args are: $2 $3 $4 $5 ..." ... you can't shift inside the echo.  But knowing zsh, I'll bet there is a way.

Comment: @rayandrews: not sure what you mean, but you can index into an array like this: `echo $a[2,-1]`  to get all but the first element. `$@` can also be treated as an array.

Comment: Thanks Thor, that's it.

Comment: @RayAndrews In zsh, you can supply an offset to arrays like `${@:1}`. This will skip the first element of the array and give you the rest. Another example: `${fpath:1}`. You can also do offset + size like `${@:1:3}` will skip the first element and give you the next three